# Access AEM component data as JSON within HTL (Sightly)

Tags: aem, sling, sightly, aem-6, sling-models

I have created a component the fields of which have been mapped to a sling model. To get the data of the sling as JSON I have enabled Sling exporter as shown in the code below -

```
@Model(adaptables = { Resource.class }, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL, resourceType = "XXX/components/content/XXX")
@Exporter(name = "jackson", extensions = "json")
public interface ProofPointsModel {

    @Inject
    List<ProofPointsList> getProofPoint();

    @Model(adaptables = { Resource.class }, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
    interface ProofPointsList {

        @Inject
        String getProofText();

        @Inject
        String getProofIcon();

    }
}
```

This works perfectly and I am able to see the JSON data when hit the end point from my browser.
I want to render this entire json object in my component's HTL. Is there an elegant way of doing this? I dont want to create an additional request to retrieve this data.
Basically I want to call this sling exporter from within my component and render the json object as is.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get .model.json as String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527180/get-model-json-as-string)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, HTL does not allow doing these "server-side includes". The workaround is to expose the JSON in a `getJson` method of your model: [Get .model.json as String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527180/get-model-json-as-string)